# View Report from even when there is no data

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

Currently it has 5 that will be generated as if it were unique, through the sub-report.

There are some reports that do not have current data.
When I run only the report it is only shown the header (correctly)
When I try to view it through the sub-report it is not shown, is there any way to only be shown the header when no data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to put the sub-report on the main report in such a way that it will be created even if there is no data in the main report.   In other words, it can't be dependent on the dataset in the main report.